# Rails 4, actions caching, why actions still runs, even when cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I have two implementation of one simple controller.

In first implementation every thing works fine, action show executing only when cache missing.
But I understand that set object @page in Proc of cache action it is a bad idea.

That's why I have second implementation, which looks much better.
It works too and returns cached view.
BUT, I can't understand why when I use `before_filter`, the action `show` is still executing even when cache hit. In log I see current time.

Could you explain me why?
please.

Implementation 1

```
class Frontend::StaticPagesController < Frontend::FrontendController

  caches_action :show, :cache_path => Proc.new {
    @page = StaticPage.find_in_cache(params[:permalink])
    {key: "#{@page.cache_key}-#{I18n.locale}"}
  }

  def show
    logger.debug Time.now.to_s.yellow
  end

end
```

Implementation 2

```
class Frontend::StaticPagesController < Frontend::FrontendController

  before_filter :set_page, :show

  caches_action :show, :cache_path => Proc.new {
    {key: "#{@page.cache_key}-#{I18n.locale}"}
  }

  def show
    logger.debug Time.now.to_s.yellow
  end

  def set_page
    @page = StaticPage.find_in_cache(params[:permalink])
  end

end
```

P.S. Rails '4.2.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
before_filter :set_page, :show
```

Defines `:show` as a filter. This is why it runs.

My guess is that you want to define the `:set_page` filter to run only for `show` action. In this is indeed your intention, use:

```
before_filter :set_page, only: :show
```

PS: `_filter` filters are deprecated. Use `_action` filters instead, like `before_action`.